# Force refresh of SVG gradient

Tags: javascript, svg, linear-gradients

I have an SVG which needs to be modified dynamically after page load.

Some elements are using `fill="currentColor"` and others are using a gradient fill, which uses `stop-color="currentColor"` in its `stop` elements. The idea is that I should be able to simply change the `color` attribute of the parent SVG and all of the child elements should automatically change color too.

This works great for the elements which are using `fill="currentColor"`, but the gradient-filled elements are not picking up the change.

Anything I can do to force a refresh?

https://jsfiddle.net/chrisAtFundrise/bb9c8gnh/

Comment: They both change for me on Firefox. Report a bug on your UA's bugtracker.

Comment: Ah yep, only been working on this in Chrome so far, should have thought of that.

Comment: Works in Edge, IE11 and FF for me. Not in Chrome.

Comment: also works in Chrome 46.0.2490.86 (macOs 64-bit) but not in Opera 33 ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a `webkit` bug! Since the `linearGradient` element is within a `defs` element, and you have `currentColor` used on your `stop` element which is not being inherited. You could also target the `linearGradient` children `<stop>` elements `stop-color` attribute.

https://jsfiddle.net/bb9c8gnh/10/

```
$("#button").on("click", function() {  
    $("svg").attr({color: "blue"});
    $("svg linearGradient stop").eq(0).attr({"stop-color": "blue", offset:"100%"});
    $("svg linearGradient stop").eq(1).attr({"stop-color": "blue"});
 });
```